Flutter/Dart: How to stop reloading the Stream on keyboard action ListView.builder
I am building a chat app that stores conversation between users on Firestore. The app is working as expected in regards to send and receiving messages, but I am struggling with the stream being rebuild everytime I use the TextField and keyboard appears.
Here is what my code looks like
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String receiverID;
  final String receiverEmail;

  const ChatScreen(
      {super.key,
      this.receiverEmail = TTrialBot.botEmail,
      this.receiverID = TTrialBot.botUserId});

  @override
  State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  /// -- Text Controller
  final TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();

  /// -- Chat & Auth Services
  final controller = UserController.instance;
  final ChatbotController _chatService = ChatbotController();
  final AgentAPIQuery _apiQuery = AgentAPIQuery();

  /// -- TextField Focus
  final FocusNode myfocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    /// -- Add Listener to focus node
    myfocusNode.addListener(() {
      if (myfocusNode.hasFocus) {
        Future.delayed(
          const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          () => scrollDown(),
        );
      }
    });

    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      () => scrollDown(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myfocusNode.dispose();
    _messageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  /// -- Scroll Controller
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  void scrollDown() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
        _scrollController.animateTo(
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent + 20000,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        );
      }
    });
  }

  /// -- Send Message
  void sendMessage() async {
    /// -- Get current User Info
    final String? currentUserID = controller.user.value.id;
    final String currentUserEmail = controller.user.value.email;

    // if there is something inside the text field
    if (_messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      var prompt = _messageController.text;

      // send message
      await _chatService.sendMessage(
          widget.receiverID, prompt, currentUserID, currentUserEmail);

      // Clear text Controller
      _messageController.clear();

      // Send Prompt
      await _apiQuery.promptRequest(prompt, currentUserID);
    }

    scrollDown();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor: TColors.secondary,
      bottomNavigationBar: _chatTextField(context),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TPrimaryHeaderContainer(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              ///TAppBar(showBackArrow: true, title: Text('Account',style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium!.apply(color: TColors.white),)),
              const SizedBox(height: TSizes.spaceBtwSections * 1.5),

              /// User Profile Card
              TChatProfileTile(
                  iconImage: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
                      ? Iconsax.user
                      : Iconsax.notification5,
                  onPressed: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
                      ? () => Get.to(() => const SettingsScreen())
                      : () => Get.to(
                          () => const CreateAccountNotificationScreen())),
              const SizedBox(height: TSizes.spaceBtwSections),
            ],
          )),
          //const SizedBox(height: 5),
          Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
            height: double.infinity,
            child: _buildMessageList(),
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMessageList() {
    String? senderID = controller.user.value.id;
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: _chatService.getMessages(widget.receiverID, senderID),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // errors
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Error');
          }
          // Loading...
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text('Loading');
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 5,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Column(
                children: snapshot.data!.docs
                    .map((doc) => _buildMessageItem(doc))
                    .toList(),
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }

  Widget _buildMessageItem(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    // Check message owner
    bool isCurrentUser = data['senderID'] == controller.user.value.id!;

    // Align message to the right of the Current User
    var alignment =
        isCurrentUser ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft;

    return Container(
        alignment: alignment,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment:
              isCurrentUser ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            ChatBuble(
              message: data['message'],
              isCurrentUser: isCurrentUser,
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget _chatTextField(context) {
    return Container(
      //color: TColors.dark,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 10,
          right: 10,
          top: 5,
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 5),
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30), color: Colors.grey),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: TextField(
              controller: _messageController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  //border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: TTexts.chatmessage,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: TSizes.fontSizeMd,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: TColors.white)),
              focusNode: myfocusNode,
            )),
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: TColors.primary,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: sendMessage,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have look into other responses on StackOverflow, but I wasn't able to figure out.
Flutter Switching to Tab Reloads Widgets and runs FutureBuilder
Using TextField inside a Streambuilder
